# noflo: Dynamic component loading - Component [name] not available with base [path]

Tags: javascript, node.js, noflo

I am getting the error:

`Component [name] not available with base [path]`

when trying to dynamically attach components to a network's ComponentLoader instance.

```
var components = []; // This is populated with noflo.Component instances at runtime.
var graph = {
    properties: { name: 'Test components' },
    processes: {
        log: { component: 'log' },
        split: { component: 'split' }
    },
    connections: [
        {
            data: 'John Doe',
            tgt: { process: 'split', port: 'in' }
        },
        {
            src: { process: 'split', port: 'left' },
            tgt: { process: 'log', port: 'in' }
        },
        {
            src: { process: 'split', port: 'right' },
            tgt: { process: 'log', port: 'in' }
        }
    ]
};

noflo.graph.loadJSON(graph, function(g) {

    noflo.createNetwork(g, function(n) {

        var getComponent = function(c) {
            return c;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {

            var c = components[i];
            n.loader.components[c.key] = {};
            n.loader.components[c.key].getComponent = getComponent.bind(null, c);

        };

    });
});
```

I have also tried assigning the component directly to the property for the components collection in the loader:

```
n.loader.components[c.key] = c;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the NoFlo ComponentLoader's `registerComponent` method for this. The trick is to start the NoFlo Network in *delayed mode* by passing it `true` as the third parameter. This way it won't start execution immediately, and you can first register your components to it.

```
// Create NoFlo network in delayed mode (see the third param in the end)
noflo.createNetwork(g, function(n) {

  // Register the custom components
  components.forEach (function (component) {
    n.loader.registerComponent('myproject', component.key, {
      getComponent: function () { return component; }
    });
  });

  // Once the components have been registered we can wire up and start it
  n.connect(function () {
    n.start();
  });

}, true);
```

The other option would be to register a custom ComponentLoader in your project. That way you wouldn't need to do anything special when starting networks.

See for example how this is done in noflo-polymer ([manifest](https://github.com/noflo/noflo-polymer/blob/master/component.json#L23), [custom loader](https://github.com/noflo/noflo-polymer/blob/master/lib/ComponentLoader.coffee#L10)) on browser or MicroFlo ([manifest](https://github.com/jonnor/microflo/blob/master/package.json#L69), [custom loader](https://github.com/jonnor/microflo/blob/master/nodejs/ComponentLoader.coffee#L10)) on Node.js.

Custom component loaders have been supported [since NoFlo 0.5.1](https://github.com/noflo/noflo/blob/master/CHANGES.md#051-may-8th-2014).